# label not updating with picker view

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I have a pickerview pulling from a datasource.  I have code to update a label in the didSelectRow function, but the label is not updating.  When I print the value to the NSLog, the proper value is printed.  Is there something special I need to do to hookup the label so that it updates when the didSelectRow is eneter?

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
if (pickerView.tag == TagLensPicker){
    [self lensArrayData];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[description objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]];
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [description objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]]);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]
```

might be the source of your problem.

`[description objectAtIndex:row]` should work

Comment: He is getting the correct value ("When I print the value to the NSLog, the proper value is printed."), so it probably isn't the source of the problem.

Comment: Either of these two codes work for updating the didSelectRow, I have the information printing to NSLog and I can also display the data in a UIAlert message, but I can get the data "pushed" to my label.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, yes, I suggested that label may not be a correct reference - see my answer somewhere around here.

Comment: @Henrik: Retaining the text is incorrect! `UILabel text` is `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *text` - it's copied anyway, and you'll only be leaking memory by not releasing it afterwards!

Comment: and yes. Maybe the label isn't wired up correctly in interface builder.

Comment: Adam, what does the code @property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *text; do?  I am new to Objective-C from Visual Basic and this aspect of setting up variables is foreign to me.  I try to define the label in the .h file with and without the @property command (and the corresponding @synthesize in the .m file), but nothing works.  The label is updated if I use [label setText:] in an IBAction, so I believe it is connected correctly, but I cannot get it to dynamically update while the pickerView UIView is selected.  I am trying to mimic the PickerView in UICatalog.

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: http://theocacao.com/document.page/510 - it explains properties quite well.

Answer (score 0):

If NSLog prints the correct value, there must be a problem with the label variable.

Print it using NSLog, see if it's a correct reference to your label?

Also, you may try calling `[label setNeedsDisplay]` after changing the text, although I'm not sure it's necessary.

Comment: I have the label defined in the .h file as
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
I then connected the label to the "Outlets" tab in IB under the Connections tab for the class the label is defined in.  Then, in the .m file, I call the code I wrote above in the didSelectRow.  I tried to copy verbatum the UICatalog example, except my label is built in IB.  I try to use both the @property command and without it (I still don't understand what @propery does).  

Do I have the label connected wrong in IB builder?  If I update the text with an IBAction, then the label is updated correctly (but not dynamically)

Comment: Your label should be `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;` Then, in the implementation of the view, use `@synthesize label;`. In the code you pasted, before `label.text = ...`, try `NSLog(@"%@", label)` and post what you got.